# getting error on checking SLServiceTypeFacebook and twitter

Tags: objective-c, facebook, ios5, twitter, social-framework

My app support iOS 5+. Now I want to add facebook and twitter. 
I added social.framework as optional and on facebook btn i check

```
if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook]) {
        NSLog(@"Facebook iOS 6 avaliable");
}
else
{
 NSLog(@"Feature not supported"); // for iOS 5 users
}
```

same for twitter. But iOS 6 Simulator works fine but iOS 5 simulator gives error. any help or tutorial for adding facebook and twitter share on iOS 5 and iOS 6 both.

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0) isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook
isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter
```

after updating project for answer 1 go this error.

[image]
here is prefix file
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x0)
```

So this error is a "segmentation fault", because the Social framework is an iOS6-only framework. Since you used weak linkage (that's what adding the framework as "optional" means), the `SLComposeViewController` class is `Nil` (i. e. it actually points to the invalid memory address `0x0`), so any function you will try to call on it will most likely result in a segmentation fault (since dereferencing this address is not possible).

What you have to do is check this class to be a valid pointer:

```
if (NSClassFromString(@"SLComposeViewController") != Nil) {
    // iOS 6
} else {
    // iOS 5, Social.framework unavailable, use Twitter.framework instead
}
```

Comment: error on if (SLComposeViewController != Nil) ... Expected Identifier

Comment: You can set the Social framework to "Optional", and then Xcode would only add it if iOS 6 or above

Comment: @RohanKapur Again, this is a *runtime* check, not a compile-time one. Also, linkage is not related to the **compiler** error OP had.

Comment: Oh alright, I get it now. Sorry for the confusion. Yeah, youre correct.

Comment: means then no need to check in app for iOS 6 and iOS 5 for this sharing....feature?

Answer (score 4):

The `Social` framework (`SLComposeViewController`) was only introduced in iOS 6. In iOS 5 the only native connection to any social network was Twitter and the `TWTweetComposeViewController` class. iOS 6 introduced the `Social` framework with pre-existing Twitter support and new Facebook and Sina Weibo integration.

So on iOS 5 you cannot actually make any reference or call to `SLComposeViewController`, you will need to use conditions to see which version (iOS 5 or 6) the user's device is running then make any operations/conditions.

The code `if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])` is used to see if the user has setup a Facebook account in the Settings application.

Yes, so you add the `Twitter` framework for iOS 5 compatibility, make sure `Social` framework is set to optional by the way.

To check what version the device is running, add this to your `MyApp-Prefix.pch` file:

```
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_EQUAL_TO(v)         ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedSame)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN(v)       ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedDescending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v) ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(v)         ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] == NSOrderedAscending)
#define SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(v)   ([[[UIDevice currentDevice] systemVersion] compare:v options:NSNumericSearch] != NSOrderedDescending)
```

Then you can use it in any class because the prefix file is automatically imported to all classes:

```
if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"5.0") && SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0")) {

       NSLog(@"This is called when device is running iOS 5, 5.0.1, 5.1 etc.");
}
else if (SYSTEM_VERSION_GREATER_THAN_OR_EQUAL_TO(@"6.0")) {

       NSLog(@"iOS 6.0, 6.0.1, 6.0.2, 6.1 etc.");
}
```

Comment: So why this code is for??? if([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeFacebook])

Comment: okx.. One more thing.. If I have twitter share. Than I must add social.framwork and twitter.framework for support iOS 6 and iOS 5.? Also tell me how to check iOS version and run the desire method written for iOS 6 and iOS 5.

Comment: This doesn't let you run the app on both iOS 5 and 6, since it detects a feature at compile time. What OP looks for is runtime checking for available features.

Comment: @user777304 Updated answer, but Im surprised you needed me to have to tell you

Comment: Use @H2CO3 answer, not mine however.